ESP32 C3 Stuck enters USB download mode
I have an ESP32 C3 12F by AI Thinker. It is connected to a flow sensor, that wakes it up via external wakeup when there is a pulse.
The system functions for about a week and then enters USB Download mode and just stays there. I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me figure out why?
I am aware that there is more information necessary in order to help here, but electronics are more of a hobby for me, so I also need help pointing me in the right direction of what question to ask, as I am not sure what information is required.

More information would be required to solve your problem. But it's clear you need more debugging information to diagnose it. It could be a stack overflow (such irony!) or many other things. Find a way to keep a computer connected to the ESP via the USB port, and add debugging statements throughout your firmware code. Look up the commands that report the stack and heap memory in use and report that too.
Since the fault only happens once a week, find a way to speed up the cycling of the system so you get meaningful information on the crash and can try fixes without waiting a week every time.
